# Curved LineString in d3 geographic projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js, lines

I'm drawing a geographic route using LineString over d3 projection, using code  like this:

```
var pts = route.paths;
pts.forEach(function(d,i) {
    g.append("path")
    .datum({
    type: "LineString", 
        coordinates: [[d.place_src.long,d.place_src.lat],[d.place_dest.long,d.place_dest.lat]], 
    })
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("stroke-linecap","round")
    .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round');
});
```

But the route is made by straight linear paths, one next the other.
There is a way to obtain curved lines (with some kind of interpolation at the node)?